# Adding to subnet's "Notes" field after ordering?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using the API (Ruby), is it possible to reliably apply text to a subnet's notes field immediately after ordering the subnets?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subnet note can’t be placed immediately after ordering a subnet, because of the provisioning time of it. This usually takes 5 minutes, and once the subnet has been provisioned a note can be applied successfully.

```
# Edits a note for a SoftLayer_Network_Subnet
# 
# Important manual pages
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/editNote
# 
# License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

network_subnet_id = 123456
note_data = 'testing note'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY)

network_subnet_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Network_Subnet')

begin
  result = network_subnet_service.object_with_id(network_subnet_id)
                                 .editNote(note_data)
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the Subnet through orderId, using the below request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getSubnets?objectFilter={"subnets":{"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation":9041210}}}}}}
```

**Replace:** $username, $apiKey and 9041210 (orderId)